# bash sed truncates file instead of replacing text

Tags: bash, sed

bash sed truncates file instead of replacing text.

I want to update variables in bashrc source with sed but to my surprise sed truncates the file.

For testing i have a little file abc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export myip=1.2.3.4
```

and this test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
myip=1.2.3.4; newip=5.6.7.8
sed -ni 's/$myip/$newip/' abc
```

running the script leaves abc empty.
Why is this so?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on an Intel I7.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the quotes that you use, the `-n` option and the absence of a `p` behind the substitute.

In bash, the single quote `'` makes sure that the text is taken literally, without variable expansion. So, you would probably want to use double quotes `"`.

Because yo use `-n`, you will probably want to print the line that you want to keep as well with the `p`:

```
sed -ni "s/$myip/$newip/p" abc
```

Note that, if you want to keep the lines that do not match, you just remove the `-n`.

Note too that the `.` in your `myip` pattern matches any character. So, your pattern `1.2.3.4` will match the `112.3.4` part of the IP address `112.3.4.9`, which will then become `5.6.7.8.9`.

Comment: Thanks, dropping the n option and using double quotes did the trick.

Comment: @user37342 you have bigger problems than that - every `.` in `$myip` will be treated as a metachar matching every other char, and the whole thing wiill match as a substring so `"s/$myip/$newip/"` would convert any string like `foo1928374bar` to `foo5.6.7.8bar` anywhere in your input. See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) and google word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your script.

1. When you enclose a string into single quotes `'`, the substitution of the bash variables will not happen. You have to use double quotes `"`.
2. If you use the `-n` option, you will produce no output except with the command `p` that you don't use.

The correct script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
myip=1.2.3.4; newip=5.6.7.8
sed -i "s/$myip/$newip/" abc
```